# How to handle error depending on error type?

Tags: javascript, python, django, react-native, django-rest-framework

I have a django view with two excpetions

```
class CreateUser(APIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def post(self, request):
        avi_pic = request.data.get('avi_pic')
        username = request.data.get('username')
        print(avi_pic)
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            return Response({'error': 'Username is already taken.'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            user = User.objects.create(avi_pic=avi_pic, username=username)
            user.save()
            serializer = UserRegisterSerializer(user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except:
            return Response({'error': 'An unexpected error occurred.'}, status=500)
```

in my React Native frontend i want to dispatch error based on the type of error but can't seem to make it work.

```
const completeSignUp = dispatch => async data => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  const username = data.user_name;
  formData.append('avi_pic', {
    uri: data.avi_pic,
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    name: data.avi_pic,
  });
  formData.append('username', username.toLowerCase());
  try {
    await axios.post(`${BACKEND_URL}/register/`, formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    }).then(res => {
      if (res.status === 200){
        const response = res.data;
        RNSInfo.setItem('user', 'true', {});
        dispatch({
          type: 'signin',
          user: 'true',
        });
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response && error.response.data === 'Username is already taken.') {
      dispatch({
        type: 'username_error',
        error: 'This username is already taken. Please choose a different one.',
      });
    } else {
      dispatch({
        type: 'error_1',
        payload: 'Something went wrong. Please try again.',
      });
    }
  }
};
```

It's only dispatching the 'error_1'

Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: 1. If the first condition is true it gonna be dispatched, check the condition
2. Proof with flipper/react-native-debugger if the action has been dispatched

Comment: Don't expect an exception will be raised when the client receives a correct HTTP response with the status 400. You should check inside the ```then(res => ...)```.